# Numpy installation API version mismatch

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I want to install numpy, pylab, scipy, and ipython on Mac OS X Lion. I installed the following:

```
python-2.7.3-macosx10.6.dmg, 
numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg, 
matplotlib-1.1.1-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg, 
scipy-0.11.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg
```

and obtained the following messages:

```
/var/folders/hm/bv37669175j2dvn_f87t4zcc0000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/statistics_intro-373260522.639.py.command ; exit;
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, TransformedPath
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 34, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import affine_transform
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Many users appear to be able to get numpy working by removing python and reinstall. I did that in `/user/bin` and `/Library`, but I still receive the error message.

Comment: What command do you use to install NumPy? Is there a specific version of NumPy that you'd need? Try installing version 4 and then move up higher.

Comment: the best thing would be install everything using macports or something similar. using ready made packages is a source for trouble.

Comment: Sadly, indeed, Python library packages on a Mac are tricky to install. homebrew, macports or fink may be one way to install things, or really try and install everything yourself from source. You may also consider a [Python bundle like Enthought](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) provides (assuming you don't need the commercial one). Btw, bad idea to remove/reinstall anything in `/usr/bin` and `/Library`: your system depends on it.

Comment: I installed version of numpy version 1.5 through 1.6, didn't work. Version 1.4 does not support Mac OS X 10.6, I didn't try it. I attempted to install ruby and received the following error: Failed during: Error: /usr/bin/xcode-select returned unexpected error. init -q.

Comment: Thanks all. I was using Lion and after seeing someone running these packages successfully on Mountain Lion, I was able to do an update on Python (not the system Python), and now I don't have error messages!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it [is using homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Basically, to get what you want, here are the steps, as root in a shell:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
brew install python # install python2.7
pip install numpy matplotlib scipy
```

and it should just work.

Comment: About the edit on whether to use or not `--framework`, I prefer to set it up, as I had recently to uninstall and reinstall python from brew only because I didn't set it as framework originally. It won't install python globally, but in case you need a decently recent version of python system-wide, you're ready to link it to /System. Otherwise there is no real difference with a unix-style installation (except the crappy osx-based directory structure, but hey, that's part of the fun of using OSX ;-) )

Comment: but after reading the comment on the edit of Samuel Jones, and verifying, indeed, from now on python builds are always frameworks per default. Thus I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on `.dmg` is asking for disappointment, as your personal setup may not match the one of the person who prepared the `.dmg`. You should really consider installing the different packages from their sources. Download the archives you want, decompress them and in each package run a

```
python setup.py install --user
```

(the `--user` ensuring that the packages will be installed in `~/.local`). Of course, you'll want to start with `numpy`, then `scipy`, then `matplotlib` and then `ipython`. Then, just make sure you add `~/.local` to your `PYTHONPATH`.

The operation, although a bit long, should be relatively painless. Make sure you have all the tools needed for the compilation, though (`XCode` is a must and you'll also need a fortran compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I had Mac OS (1) Upgrade from Lion to Mountain Lion (2) update Python (3) had it point to Python27 instead of system Python. This doesn't explain why Python in Lion is broken, but I no longer receive the error messages!